# Trying to have additional form checkboxes in a bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have an input field that accepts and then a submit button. When clicking the submit button I want a popover to appear that has checkboxes that you need to agree to before you can submit the form. Once the checkboxes have been selected, the button that the popover appeared on can be clicked again to submit the form.

The issue I am having is once the checkboxes are selected and then the submit button is clicked again the checkbox data in the popover disappears and the form does not submit as I have a required tag on the checkboxes.

Here is the code that I have so far.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="signup" class="needs-validation resize-form form-inline" 
action="/api/users/signup" method="POST"
novalidate>
    <div class="form-group auto">
      <div class="custom-control col is-invalid">
        <div id="result">
          <label for="phone"></label>
          <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type=tel id="phone" 
          name="phone"
            placeholder="Enter Phone Number" autocomplete="off" required>
        </div>
        <input id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" type="hidden">
        <input id="ref" name="ref" type="hidden" value="<%= ref %>">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button type="submit" id="popover" class="tagline-btn btn btn-        
         outline-primary btn-lg">
        Sign Up
        </button>
        <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="statement1" 
            required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="statement1">Statement         
            1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="statement2" 
            required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="statement2">Statement 
            2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript + Jquery code:**

```
$('#popover').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
      return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
  });

  var reset = function () {
    errorMsg.classList.remove("d-block");
  };

  (function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();

  input.addEventListener('keydown', reset);
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: One thing that I would make sure to do is give your checkboxes a NAME. They have type, class, id and required but no name.